# Problem with Toolstrip WinForms .Net Core

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core, click, toolstrip

I'm making a Winforms application in .Net Core to learn some basic stuff. It's a simple application where I write some text from a textbox to a file (basically like notepad).

Now I wanted to add a toolstrip with a toolstripbutton to make a new file and a toolstripbutton to save the text to the file, etc..

So I add the toolstrip from toolbox and drag it to my form1.cs[design]. Then I right click on the toolstrip and click "Insert standard items". The buttons are being added to the toolstrip.

Now my problem is I want to add a click event to the buttons but I can't double click the toolstripbuttons individually. So I have to go into the designer.cs to add the click event. For example:

```
this.newToolStripButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnNewFile_Click);
```

I just tried it with a WinForms app in .Net Framework and there I can just double click the toolstripbuttons to add an eventhandler.

Do I have to take a different approach in .Net Core? Is this not yet fully supported in .Net Core and should I just use .Net Framework for Winforms? I read that not all of the functionalities from Winforms in .Net Framework are yet supported in .Net Core, but Toolstrip should work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used WinForms with .NET Core so far but according to [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/windows-forms-designer-for-net-core-released/) (published in May of this year), the `ToolStripContainer` control is not supported yet.

Comment: Ok that explains it, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of Visual Studio 2019 16.8.0 Preview 6.0 (and also VS2019 16.7.6), double-clicking a ToolStripButton in the designer will launch code for the ToolStrip_ItemClicked event.  In that event you can check the ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs.ClickedItem to see what was pressed.

```
private void toolStrip2_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripButton tsb = (ToolStripButton)e.ClickedItem;
        }
```

If you want to get to the Click event for an individual ToolStripButton, you can select it in the Properties window, click the Events button, and insert it there.